# iOS Facebook SDK Login View sometimes shows Desktop Web rather than Mobile Web

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

I'm using the latest FB SDK via Pods - version 3.18.2, with Xcode 5 in and iPhone only app. I use the FBLoginView in the Storyboard, so tapping it pops open the Facebook login for the app, and login actions call the delegate of the parent View controller of that FBLoginView button.

It all works fine -- but, sometimes the Desktop version of the login shows up rather than the Mobile version. It's intermittent -- I have tester where it never shows, one who gets it sometimes, and one who gets it often.

Any idea how I can prevent the SDK from showing the Desktop login?

Answer (score 0):

If the user doesn't have the Facebook native app installed the facebook website will open. 
Otherwise it will open the Facebook native app.

Comment: The question is how to force the SDK to always load the mobile version(m.facebook.com) when the Facebook app isn't present.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called openWithBehavior in the Facebook SDK that works on sessions. Use that like I have shown below:

```
FBSession *session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email",@"user_location",@"user_birthday",@"user_likes"]];
[FBSession setActiveSession:session];


[session openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView
        completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                            FBSessionState status,
                            NSError *error) {



            if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {

//Do Something
}
}
]
```

Comment: I don't want to force web view -- and I want the SDK to use the normal Web pop up that it is using now, in case the user does not have a Facebook app or login activated in Settings.

Comment: Then there is another function at the same place to login if the account is there. Check that out.